# How to fix image link to attachment page wordpress

Tags: wordpress, attachment

I have a Big problem regarding image link attachment page, since that terrible day that yoast made that update to plugin some of my posts (have 17.000+) image have double name example.com/post1/post1 is not redirecting to example.com/post1 like is normal … it`s redirecting to example.com/post1/post1 and guess how many error i have in google cosole…

Any welcome will be more then welcome

Regards

(yes, i asked yoast and no help since im not a premium subscriber)

Comment: Have you tried flushing the permalinks? Literally just go to the permalinks settings and wp will ‘refresh’ them

Comment: Yes, already did that

Comment: cezars, It sounds like this is the problem? Have you followed these steps and understand how to eventually resolve the google errors? http://infobunny.com/seo-problem/

Comment: Thank you again anmari for the answer, i already did that but i dont know how to fix that problem with image that create link example.com/post1/post1 and not how it should be example.com/post1